# jQuery DataTables - sorting does not work when date is also a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I notices that UK date sorting does not work when a date is also a link.

Example 1. ([demo](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17683975/blog/DataTables%20-%20Sort%20by%20UK%20Date%20-%20without%20HREF/index.html))

**Here the date is pure test. Works complete fine.**

```
       <tr>
            <td>01/01/01</td>
            <td>Tarik</td>
            <td>Rashad Kidd</td>
            <td>1 34 238 6239-0509</td>
        </tr>
```

Example 2. ([demo](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17683975/blog/DataTables%20-%20Sort%20by%20UK%20Date%20-%20with%20HREF/index.html))

**Here the date is also a link. Does not work at all. Not throwing any errors though.**

```
         <tr>
            <td><a href="#">01/01/01</a></td>
            <td>Tarik</td>
            <td>Rashad Kidd</td>
            <td>1 34 238 6239-0509</td>
        </tr>
```

**I also noticed that the sorting does work on any other elements even if they are a link. Only the date as a link are the issue.**

I'm using the following JS code:

```
// UK Date Sorting
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-asc']  = function(a,b) {
    var ukDatea = a.split('/');
    var ukDateb = b.split('/');

    var x = (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    var y = (ukDateb[2] + ukDateb[1] + ukDateb[0]) * 1;

    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-desc'] = function(a,b) {
    var ukDatea = a.split('/');
    var ukDateb = b.split('/');

    var x = (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    var y = (ukDateb[2] + ukDateb[1] + ukDateb[0]) * 1;

    return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ?  -1 : 0));
}


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#table').dataTable( {
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "aoColumnDefs" : [
            { "aTargets" : ["uk-date-column"] , "sType" : "uk_date"}
        ]
    });

});
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you sorting function is confused by the extra html. You should modify your functions like this:

```
// UK Date Sorting
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-asc']  = function(a,b) {  
    //use text()
    var ukDatea = $(a).text().split('/');
    var ukDateb = $(b).text().split('/');

    var x = (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    var y = (ukDateb[2] + ukDateb[1] + ukDateb[0]) * 1;

    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-desc'] = function(a,b) {
    //use text()
    var ukDatea = $(a).text().split('/');
    var ukDateb = $(b).text().split('/');

    var x = (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    var y = (ukDateb[2] + ukDateb[1] + ukDateb[0]) * 1;

    return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ?  -1 : 0));
}
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/GUb2n/

Comment: Thanks! Can you just explain what have you change and why? Much appreciated!

Comment: @NewUser i used `var ukDatea = $(a).text().split('/');` instead of `var ukDatea = a.split('/');`. in this way the date can be split correctly because you are getting only the text of the link and not the markup

Comment: Nice! Very simple and straight forward solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try to put the date (in ISO Format) in an invisible container in front of the link:

```
<span style="display: none;">2001-01-01</span><a href="#">01/01/01</a>
```

Then alphabetic sort should work.

Comment: lol - this actually works perfectly! simple and elegant! I actually put the hidden date using (strtotime($date)) to get the number version - which is sorted automatically

Comment: This is the simplest and quickest solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, improper sorting of linkified data has to do with the way DataTables attempts to strip HTML from the content of a table cell (using a simplified regexp) which seems unable to completely extract date data from the cell.

DataTables 1.10+ can use [HTML 5 data attributes](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) to avoid this problem.

If you have a link in a set of `<td>` tags, like this:

```
<td><a href = "someobject">28 July 2015</a></td>
```

you can add a `data-order` attribute to your `<td>` tag:

```
<td data-order="2015-07-28"><a href = "someobject">28 July 2015</a></td>
```

This `data-order` attribute lets DataTables sort on the `data-order` attribute and use the content between your `<td>` tags as display data only.

Answer (score 0):

*(v1.9.4)* This solution not only fixes your sorting woes but also fixes filtering issues because normally the filter matches against the HTML, so searching for things like `href` or `div`end up matching all the rows.

It strips away the HTML inside the `mRender` option and then caches the result since DataTables runs the `mRender` function multiple times.

**[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sparebytes/XL7Wh/)**

***Warning** for Editable Tables*

An editable table may have issues due to the Caching mechanism.

**Step1**

Include the following javascript somewhere:

```
var stripHtml = (function() {
    var tmpDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    return function(html) {
        tmpDiv.innerHTML = html;
        return $.trim(tmpDiv.textContent || tmpDiv.innerText);
    };
})();

var mRenderFactory = function (colIndex) {
    return function (data, type, full) {
        var cache = MRenderCache.getCache(full);

        if (type === "filter" || type === "sort" || type === "type") {
            return cache.getOrElse(colIndex, data, stripHtml)
        }
        return data;
    };
};

var MRenderCache = function () {
    this.full = [];
}
MRenderCache.getCache = function (full) {
    var cache = full[full.length - 1];
    if (cache == null || !cache.MRenderCache) {
        cache = new MRenderCache();
        full.push(cache);
    }
    return cache;
}
MRenderCache.prototype.MRenderCache = true;
MRenderCache.prototype.getOrElse = function (colIndex, rawData, convert) {
    var result = this.full[colIndex];
    if (result === undefined) {
        result = convert(rawData);
        this.full[colIndex] = result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Step 2**

Set `"mRender": mRenderFactory(i)` inside `aoColumns` on any columns you want the HTML stripped where `i` is the index of the column. It is VERY important you get the right `i` because if you don't then the table will display fine but will sort and filter on the wrong column.

You're initialization code would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            { "mRender": mRenderFactory(2) },
            { "mRender": mRenderFactory(3) },
            null
        ]
    } );
} );
```