# JQuery Datatables: Links and plain text is sorted separate

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, columnsorting

I try to create a Datatable using JQuery and sort it based on the first column. This column contains both links and plain text.

JQuery apparently sorts them separately, so first the links alphabetically and below the plain text alphabetically.

How can I mix them together, so that every text format is considered the same?
I already tried a bunch of solutions, including column-type definition, custom order definition... None of them works properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#toollist').dataTable({
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "scrollY": "500px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 50, 100],
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>

<table id="toollist" class="table display table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="https://www.google.com">
                <strong>A</strong></a></td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <strong>A</strong></td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <strong>B</strong></td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="https://www.google.com">
                <strong>B</strong></a></td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="https://www.google.com">
                <strong>C</strong></a></td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <strong>C</strong></td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​
```

Comment: I think you might find your solution here: https://datatables.net/development/sorting

Comment: Thanks for your link. Unfortunately  I tried this one before and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Is it possible that you've added something to your code that breaks the default behavior?

Comment: The posted Code snippet is all thats in the code

Comment: I also tried letting out Bootstrap, but that doesn't make any difference

Comment: What version of DataTables are you using?

Comment: https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: I don't see anything obvious and anything after v 1.6 is supposed to have solved this problem. You might need to post this on the data tables forum instead.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help.

Comment: Just posted it here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/43509/links-and-plain-text-are-sorted-separately#latest

Comment: Please come back and post the solution when you figure it out and leave a comment.

Comment: Just so I understand -  the first column can contain a link or a string, and you want to sort on the string only?

Comment: yes, I want the strings and links to be sorted equally

Comment: Maybe this post help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17732714/1883345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Sharepoint specific charset issue.
The answer to the problem is on following Datatables forum feed:
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/43509/links-and-plain-text-are-sorted-separately#latest

However, there is also a very helpful sorting plugin posted from allan.